SFMC Newbie: Need to create a segmented email list/data extension
I accidentally sent an email out to an old large data extension, instead of the current updated list.
I need to send the email out again, excluding anyone that already received it if they were included in the original send.
What are the steps I would need to follow (i.e. what to click) to cross-reference the recipients on the list with those on the current list, so I can create a email list to send to?
I know...total SFMC Newbie! Have searched for SF;s expert support/docs, but don't seem to get the step by step tutorial I'm looking for. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Based on what you provided, you can use Send Flow for Content Builder emails in Email Studio.
Go to Email Studio >> Content. From there you can click Send from the dropdown for Content Builder emails.
The steps are also mentioned in the article above.
In the Select Audience step, you can select which data sources can be used for the send and which ones can be used for the exclusion.

